# vscode + vim plugin: CTRL+P no longer works

Tags: visual-studio-code

I've used vscode with the vim plugin for years. All of a sudden I can no longer open files using CTRL+P. Looks like the plug-in intercepts this combination and moves the cursor up instead.

Comment: This doesn't directly help you, but I suggest using the neovim plugin instead. That extension doesn't emulate neovim, but uses a real instance in the background. And neovim can just load vimrcs, so the switch is really just install neovim and the plugin and write a 3 line configfile. See: [`:help nvim-from-vim`](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim.html#nvim-from-vim). What made me switch was all the inconsistencies with the emulator and using vim-surround with functions :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It looks like this [issue was introduced in v1.26.0](https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8574) a few days ago. If you don't use Ctrl+P to navigate in the filepicker, you can disable or change the vim shortcut back to the default VSCode behavior, as noted in the issue:

```
// keybindings.json
{
    "key": "ctrl+p",
    "command": "workbench.action.quickOpen"
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the preferred solution in the issue thread: https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/8574#issuecomment-1715573738  Adding the referenced code to my 'settings.json' (Shift-Ctrl-P --> Preferences: Open User Settings (JSON)) fixes the issue for me.

Answer (score 24):

In the `settings.json` you can also tweak the vim plugin to ignore some keys:

Set to `true` or `false` the key combination you would like the vim plugin to react to:

```json
"vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-p>": false
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I used this way

```
ctrl + shift + e // switch to explorer
ctrl + p         // find something
ctrl + shift + e // back to workspace
```

Answer (score 2):

The easier thing to do is to use `ctrl+shift+p` (which still works) and then delete the '`>`' that appears in the search box. This turns the box into the file picker.